# Webkit-greeter only changes after a restart, not when logging out or locking computer

Tags: 14.04, unity, login, lightdm, login-screen

On Ubuntu 14.04, I installed the lightdm-webkit-greeter using `sudo apt-get install lightdm-webkit-greeter`

then, I did the following to get the greeter I wanted:

```
cd /usr/share/lightdm-webkit/themes/
sudo git clone http://github.com/omgmog/lightdm-webkit-google.git
sudo sed -i 's/unity-greeter/lightdm-webkit-greeter/g' /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
sudo sed -i 's/default/lightdm-webkit-google/g' /etc/lightdm/lightdm-webkit-greeter.conf
```

This works great and I get the login I want everytime I power up the computer.

The problem is, that when I log out or lock the computer, I get the regular Unity log-in screen.

Anyone knows how to change the greeter globaly? So on log out and lock I'll get the same greeter?

thanks!